# Why add a "_" before parameter list

Tags: c, gcc

When I read some code which run on linux and is compiled by gcc, I meet a declaration like that:

```
void* (*func_name) _((void *buf, int size))
```

The BGET source code is that:

```
void bectl _((int (*compact)(bufsize sizereq , int sequence), 
    void *(*acquire)(bufsize size),
    void *(*release)(void *buf),
    bufsize pool_incr));
void bectl(compact, acquire, release, pool_incr)
    int(*compact) _((bufsize sizereq, int sequence));
    void *(*acquire) _((bufsize size));
    void (*release) _((void *buf));
    bufsize pool_incr;
    {

    }
```

The question is that I don't know why add "_" before parameter list.

Comment: Who wrote the code? Why not ask them?

Comment: FWIW, cdecl.org reckons it's a syntax error.

Comment: I get a syntax error too (VC2008).

Comment: Confirmed in GCC trunk. `_` here could be a macro. This really is a textbook example of how _not_ to write code.

Comment: It's probably a macro for pre-ANSI compatibility, when prototypes didn't exist.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sir, what is GCC trunk?

Comment: @ARBY: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trunk_(software) Final year CS and they haven't taught you version control? That's pretty bad. :(

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, they haven't. Sorry my bad. Added version control to to-do.

Comment: @ARBY: Their bad. That's really appalling for a University course on CS :( My condolences.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's an example of how to write code when you can't depend on your compiler to support prototypes. The code in question is *old*. See my answer.

Comment: @KeithThompson: If the author had thought to write some documenting comments or mention this in the documentation, then _maybe_. As it is, it's just unclear. Don't really care how old it is - that doesn't change how bad it is. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, it's fairly obvious if you take a look at `bget.h`, and it was a common technique at the time. And manual configuration was also common back then (as opposed to the modern `configure&&make&&make install`). But yes, the meaning of `_` and `PROTOTYPE` certainly should have been mentioned in `bget.doc` (which is plain text, not MS Word).

Comment: @KeithThompson: Well, by "this", I meant the code as posted in the question. If the source has better documentation then the source is better than this "version". :) But then why didn't the OP simply read it? Hmm....

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It's not that much better. On the other hand, it didn't take me long to figure it out, and a typical C 1995 C programmer probably wouldn't have had much trouble with it either.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I shan't delve into a comparison of new developers in 1995 versus new developers in 2016 ;) It would be frightfully negative for a mild Sunday evening.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`_` is a macro intended to allow the code to use prototypes (function declarations that specify the types of the parameters) while still being compatible with pre-ANSI compilers that don't support prototypes.

Note that `_` is a valid identifier. However, all identifiers starting with `_` are reserved for use at file scope, so this is one more reason the code is potentially non-portable.

The code you're reading is apparently BGET, available [here](http://www.fourmilab.ch/bget/). (It would have been helpful to cite the source in your question.) If you look at the `bget.h` header file (last updated in 1995), you'll see:

```
#ifndef _
#ifdef PROTOTYPES
#define  _(x)  x                      /* If compiler knows prototypes */
#else
#define  _(x)  ()                     /* It it doesn't */
#endif /* PROTOTYPES */
#endif
```

Today, 21 years later, there are very few C compilers in use that don't support prototypes, so the need for such macros is largely obsolete. But even the latest ISO C standard, published in 2011, still supports old-style non-prototype functions.

Note that there's nothing in the source that actually defines the `PROTOTYPES` macro, so if you want to compile the code with prototypes enabled (to get additional compile-time checking), you'll need to manually edit the `makefile`, changing this:

```
COPTS = -O
```

to this:

```
COPTS = -O -DPROTOTYPES
```

Even with that change, compilation still fails because of the invalid redeclaration of `malloc`. The code needs some work to bring it up to modern standards.